# Saving files to separate html file before using grep/sed

Tags: bash, curl, sed, grep, wget

I'm working on a project that lets me navigate some urls. Right now I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1
do
wget $1 >> output.html
cat output.html | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | 
sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' |
sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d' |
grep 'http'
done
```

I want the user to be able to run the script as follows:

```
./navigator google.com
```

which will save the source of url into a new html file, which will then run my grep/seds and then save to a new file.

Right now I'm struggling with saving the url into a new html file. Help!

Comment: You can use: `wget "$1" -O "output-$1.html"`

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way to not show the process of wget? To do it behind the scenes? I'd like it to look pretty smooth, like

    ./navigator google.com
    urls ...
    urls ...

vs.
    ./navigator google.com
    resolving google.com ....

Comment: `nv` = no verbose..., `-q` = quiet

Comment: `wget -q "$1" -O "output-$1.html"`

Comment: @anubhava It looks like you've answered the question. It would be better to copy your answer into the answer field so Mike can upvote / accept it.

Comment: ok fair enough, I will post it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new file for each URL, use url in your output filename for `wget -O` option:

```
#!/bin/bash

for url; do
   out="output-$url.html"
   wget -q "$url" -O "$out"

   grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' "$out" | 
     sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' |
     sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d' |
     grep 'http'
done
```

**PS:** As per comments above, added `-q` in `wget` to make it totally quiet.